# SBS2011 - Exchange 2010 - Does removing user remove mail-account?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs

We're running an Small Business Server 2011 with Exchange 2010. We recently had a few changes in our employees, so we have 3 users that have to go.

What happens if I delete the user? Will the emailaccount be deleted automatically? Or can I 'save' the emailaccount so the emails that they still get don't get lost?

Answer (score 1):

don't delete ad users when there a mailboxes associated with them.
exchange may purge the associated storage but in general - afaik - there's no way to access the mailboxes anymore (as exchange relies heavily on the ad infrastructure for configuration / accounts).

i recommend to disable the user accounts until you have no need to access the mails anymore. using access control you can attach the mailboxes to other accounts that need to have access to the mailboxes.